# Easier-to-type alternative to std::cout for printing to screen in C++

Tags: c++, printf, cout

Often I just want to quickly check the contents of a series of variables (let's call them a,b,c,d and e, and suppose they're a mixture of floats, integers and strings). I'm fed up typing

```
cout << a << " " << b << " " << " " << c << " " << " " << d << " " << e << endl;
```

Is there a more convenient (less key-strokes) way to quickly dump a few variables to stdout in C++? Or do C++ people just always define their own simple print function or something? Obviously something like

```
printf("%d %f %s %d %s\n",a,b,c,d,e);
```

is not the alternative I'm looking for, but rather something like

```
print a,b,c,d,e
```

Even

```
print*, a,b,c,d,e
```

or

```
write(*,*) a,b,c,d,e
```

isn't too inconvenient to type.

Of course, googling 'quickly print to screen in C++' keeps just sending me back to std::cout.

Comment: Well, a typesafe `print(a,b,c,d,e);` is easy to make, but you have to consider who's reading it later and whether the semantics are clearly defined.

Comment: If these are automatic variables, the debugger GDB automagically displays them in a window called "Locals", and keeps them up-to-date during single step.

Comment: it would be more complicated, rather you should go with `cin>>` its easiest and also provides feature like cascading.

Comment: KUDOS... I want to commend you on your (early?) experiments on using std:cout (and / or std::cerr) for debugging. I have worked on big teams (>75 developers) where the standard operating procedure (SOP) was to use 'removeable' printf's (and lately removable std::cout's) for all but the most difficult debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more convenient (less key-strokes) way to quickly dump a
>   few variables to stdout in C++?

I would have to say No, not in the language.  But I do not consider std::cout a challenging amount to type.

You can tryout the template methods provided by other answer's.

But you *should* try GDB (or some debugger available on your system).  GDB can 'dump' automatic variables with *no* _effort_ at all, as automatic var's for the current stack frame are always kept up-to-date in the "Locals" window.

> Or do C++ people just always define their own simple print function or something?

No, or maybe something.

I use std::cout and std::cerr (as defined) for lots of debugging, but not in the 'how can I save the most typing' frame of mind.

My view is that creating a 'convenience' (i.e. not required) function is appropriate for doing something you wish to repeat.  My rule of thumb is 3 times ... if I do a particular something 3 (or more) times (like generate a std::cout statement with the same or similar variables in it) then I might write a function (rather than copy the line) for that repeated effort.

Typically, I use one of two (what I call) disposable debug methods ... and most of my objects also have both show() and dump(), and there can be multiple show/dump functions or methods, each with different signatures, and default values.

```
 if(dbg1) show(a,b,c,d,e); 
 if(dbg1b) show(b);
 // etc
```

and

```
 if(dbg2) dump(a,b,c,d,e);
```

Show typically uses and does what what std::cout provides, and little else.

Dump does what show does, but also might provide an alternate view of the data, either hex or binary translations of the values, or perhaps tables.  What ever helps.

Disposable does not mean I will dispose of them, but rather I might, and I often get tired of output that does not change, so I set dbgX to false when this code seems to be working, at least until I decide to dispose of the debug invocation.

But then, you do have to implement each of the functions and methods, and yes, you are going to have to learn to type.

If these variables are automatic, you should know that the debugger GDB automatically displays them in a window called "Locals", and keeps them up-to-date during single step.

In GDB, object instance contents can often be displayed with "p *obj", and there are ways to add a particular obj name to the local display window.

It does not take a lot to run GDB.  If you object to creating the 80 char std::cout code above, it takes far less typing to launch GDB, set break in main, and run the simple task under gdb control, (then single step to observe these variables at *any* step in your code) not just where you happened to insert a show() or dump() command.

And if you have GDB, you can also command to print using "p show()" (when the show() function is in scope) to see what the in-scope variables look like to std::cout (if you don't believe the "Locals" window).

GDB allows you to  "p this->show()" when stepping through a method of the instance,  or "p myObj->show()" when the myObj is accessible.

ALso, "p *this" and "p *myObj" will provide a default, typically useful, display of the current contents your object.

Anyway.  Yes you can always work hard to shorten your typing effort.

Answer (score 8):

Is it that, what you want?

```
print(a, b, c);
```

That would be this.

```
template <typename T>
void print(T t)
{
  std::cout << t << " ";
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T t, Args... args)
{
  std::cout << t << " ";
  print(args...) ;
}
```

Comment: How would one add a "\n" at the end of all args? (so that it prints `std::endl` after all arguments are print?

Comment: @TheClockTwister  Just change std::cout << t << " "; to std::cout << t << std::endl;

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to create a "print" class which have an overloaded template `operator,`, then you could do something like

```
print(),a,b,c,d;
```

The expression `print()` would create a temporary instance of the `print` class, and then use that temporary instance for the printing with the comma operator. The temporary instance would be destroyed at the end of the expression (after last comma overload is called).

The implementation could look something like this:

```
struct print
{
    template<typename T>
    print& operator,(const T& v)
    {
        std::cout << v;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note: This is just off my head, without any testing.

Comment: As an extra feature you could have std::endl in destructor.

Comment: I like this.  But you forgot the space after/between the variable values.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Details details... :)

Comment: Slept on it ... decided it was only the second good use for comma operator I have learned.  Thank you.  Here is +1.

Comment: Works.  And yes, std::endl in DTOR works as needed (thanks @user2672165)  Not sure I like it because it looks so different.  But I think its growing on me.